# How to access build in explorer in android 5.0.2

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, settings, my-files

I would like to know how i can access the build in explorer as we can from android 6 like This way setting>storage and USB>explorer but in android 5 no explorer is there, i can access through pictures, audio, misc only there is there any app which let use build in explorer, i am willing to download any app to access the totally stock build in explorer.

Comment: On older Android devices and versions, there is no stock file explorer at all. Even Nexus 4 and 5 didn't have one. It depends if the manufacturer preinstalls one.

Comment: But am able to access with like open WhatsApp select documents send option and there it was shown and some feature in setting>storages>misc